# Print first occurrence of a line in bash

Tags: perl, bash, awk

I extracted ORFs from a initial fasta file and now I want to get the longest ORF for each transcript.

After having extracted the size of the ORFs with faSize and sorted them by size, 
the code I was used to use is:

```
perl -ane'print unless $x{$F[0]}++'
```

This time I have a problem using the perl command.

After having extracted the size and sorted the transcripts I have something like this:

```
Singlet_1000_61         3844 
Singlet_2000_73         3508 
Singlet_1000_62         3081 
Singlet_2000_62         3008 
Singlet_3500_48         2973 
Singlet_4000_48        2964 
Singlet_3500_54        2863
```

What I want is:

```
Singlet_1000_61         3844 
Singlet_2000_73         3508
Singlet_3500_48         2973
...
```

The perl command is not working in this case.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can make it work?

Or a awk command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only looking at

```
Singlet_1000_61 3844
        ^^^^
```

is ok,

```
 perl -F_ -ane'print unless $x{$F[1]}++'
```

If you want to look at

```
Singlet_1000_61 3844
^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

then

```
perl -ane'$F[0] =~ s/_[^_]*\z//; print unless $x{$F[0]}++'
```

Comment: The first one works perfectly fine!Thanks...this is what I was looking at but I am not expert of Perl at all...Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Print each line that first has the second part of the line split by underscores.

```
awk -F_ '!s[$2]++' <<< 'Singlet_1000_61 3844
Singlet_2000_73 3508
Singlet_1000_62 3081
Singlet_2000_62 3008
Singlet_3500_48 2973
Singlet_4000_48 2964
Singlet_3500_54 2863
'
Singlet_1000_61 3844
Singlet_2000_73 3508
Singlet_3500_48 2973
Singlet_4000_48 2964
```

Comment: This particular awk command grows in memory depending on how many times `$2` is unique. If you have `$2=1000` a million times, it will be very small, but if you have a million *different* values for $2 it will be pretty large.

Comment: The same with Perl would be `perl -F_ -ane'print unless $x{$F[1]}++'`

Comment: @user1819854 You can only have one accepted answer, but you can upvote many. Since you marked ikegami's answer accepted, you unmarked mine. Is that what you intended to do?